# Templating a secondary menu with linking pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with Razor C# and I have implemented a main menu appearing on every page through _Layout.cshtml.

One of the pages linked to this menu opens a page that includes a secondary menu. 
This page with the secondary menu links to several different pages which are navigated via the same secondary menu.

I've used Partial views to hold each secondary menu page, and I'm wondering what is the easiest/preferred way to output these partial pages via the page with the secondary menu? (Or perhaps I shouldn't even be using Partial views to save having to add the secondary menu to each page).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, A friend, who is also working on the same problem, just showed me this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrlU8sr5Tqc
So the answer seems to be Nested Layouts.